# Help identifying pieces in ambiguous wall anchor kit

Tags: drywall, screws, studs, anchor

I’m a newbie at installing things into the studs / drywall, and I need some help identifying how to use what is included in this wall rack mount kit.

- Three yellow pieces (anchors?)
- Three long screws
- Two gray drywall screws
- Two long thin screw
- Three screw caps

Am I supposed to use the yellow pieces if installing into a stud?

I’m thinking I should forego the yellow pieces and simply use the screw into the wood. It seems like the yellow sheath wouldn’t let the screw threads hold into the wood as well.

[image]

Also, I have no idea how the drywall screws are supposed to work given the mount screw holes are much thinner. Do i screw a second screw into the gray screws if mounting in the drywall?

Comment: Can you take everything out of the bag, line it up on top of a white piece of paper and upload a picture of everything, straight on, no glare.

Comment: Hah, I got that same exact kit recently, and the confusing looking bag of hardware caused me to spend an hour reading about wall fasteners!

Answer (score 14):

OK, the yellow anchors do not go into the studs. They can be used in drywall, brick, masonry, etc when the proper size hole is drilled. Those big threaded anchors are for drywall. They have a sharp point and you screw them into the wall with a Phillips screwdriver and tighten them up so they indent a little into the drywall. Then one of your smaller silver screws get screwed into the center of the anchor. If you locate the stud, you can screw some of the silver screws directly into the studs after drilling a small pilot hole. The black caps just go over the installed screws to cover the heads for appearance.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that getting as many screws into the wall studs as possible will result in a much stronger attachment to the wall...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  Definitely agree. Mounting into the studs is the way to go.

Comment: Those ‘anchors’ are known as [wall plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_plug)s (or Rawlplugs) in the UK.

Comment: In this case, going into studs would not use any of the anchors - just the wood screws into the studs is all that is needed. The yellow ones would be strictly for masonry in this application as they would not provide sufficient hold in drywall for a mechanical support. The light gray EZ-Anchors would be for use in drywall where a stud is not available.  EZ-Anchors usually hold about 20kg shear in drywall (depending on size), the yellow ones in drywall aren't for anything more than hanging a picture frame. All of those anchors need appropriate pre-drilling also (this isn't clear in the answer).

Comment: @J...  " when the proper size hole is drilled."  is stated in the answer and the larger drywall anchors do not get pre-drilled.They're designed to  bore their own hole.

Comment: @JACK Fair enough - I always find EZ-anchors are hit and miss if you don't pre-drill, but yeah, you can just slam them in if you want, that's acceptable.  The main point I wanted to make was that the yellow anchors are no good for significant load-bearing applications in drywall but they are solid in masonry/brick.

Answer (score 8):

You appear to have 5 anchors and 3 screws. I hope this isn't much of a rack, or that you're willing to go buy some <s>screws.</s> Lag Bolts.

The things you are referring to as *drywall screws* appear to be screw-in *drywall anchors*, which then take a normal screw in the center of the anchor. They hold fairly well for a drywall anchor, but unless it's a *very* small, *light* rack with *not much weight* of equipment in it, not suitable.

The yellow anchors are for solid walls,  - brick, concrete block or solid concrete. They are also used on drywall but don't hold very well compared to the whitesh/gray ones. In holes in solid masonry they will hold pretty well, but you only have 3 of them...

If you can line up with a stud, or better yet two studs, just use the screws directly, no anchors. Or use some better screws, since those thrown in with imported racks may be of fairly poor quality, as screws go.

I mount racks for work. They are *not* small, light nor lightly loaded. They have multiple thousands of dollars worth of stuff in them and it would be **very bad** if they fell down. Since racks rarely manage to have holes that hit two studs, or if they do, someone doesn't want the rack "just there" standard procedure is to screw a sheet of plywood to the studs, and screw the rack to the plywood. If we can hit one of the studs as well, great, but we don't *need* to at that point. Use the biggest lag bolt (diameter wise) that will fit the holes in the rack, and use at least 4 of them unless it's vanishingly small. Length-wise, if mounting to plywood, they just need to be a bit longer than the plywood is thick for full holding power. Use washers as well, and allow for the washers and rack thickness as well as the plywood thickness when selecting the length.

Comment: The original picture suggests this is a rack for surfboards, not servers, and the website listed on the piece of the paper looks to sell outdoor stuff. Rack != Servers. What about bikes, spices, clothes, etc?

Comment: I ended up installing two things: this above surf rack as well as a heavy duty pull up bar. I ended up going with the drywall anchors for the surf rack (it doesn't support much weight, surfboards are vertically standing on mostly their own support). As for the pull up bar, I have three lag screws per side going into three rows of 3/4" plywood which I secured each with 8 pilot holes + 3" thick screws into the studs. So far it's holding up great!! Thanks for the awesome tips for someone who knew nothing and now is feeling a bit more confident! The instructionals at HD also helped a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell exactly with everything in the bag. But the yellow anchors are "hollow wall anchors" - designed to be used with screws (which are almost certainly included). There also should be some screws that are designed to go through drywall and into studs - you do **not** use any plastic parts with those. There are probably a few other types of anchors as well, but can't tell in the bag.

Comment: The yelllow things look more to me like plugs designed for use in solid masonary walls.